# webpack-dev-server does not update served bundle

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Here's my webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: './js',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

I start the webpack-dev-server like this: `webpack-dev-server --inline` from the root directory of my app.

The problem is when I make changes in my index.js file it looks like the dev-server is bundling in the console, but I see no changes in the browser. Even after manually refreshing the served bundle.js does not change (I'm looking at it in the developer tools, I know that webpack-dev-server serves the file from memory and doesn't write changes to the file system).

Is there anything wrong in my webpack configuration or do I need to configure the webpack-dev-server somehow?

Comment: How do you refer your `bundle.js`? And which url do you use to view the page? http://localhost:8080/?

Comment: I use localhost:8080 and my site uses bundle.js like this: `<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Run server as `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot`

Comment: @BobSponge Now the output in the console is slightly different, the problem is still the same.

Comment: Any output in browser console?

Comment: @BobSponge only the message about the react devtools

Comment: From docs: `It’s important to specify a correct output.publicPath otherwise the hot update chunks cannot be loaded.`

Comment: @BobSponge thats it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bob Sponge mentioned in the comments the problem is that the `output.publicPath` is missing. I've updated my config like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: './js',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'js/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Nice one! publicPath was the answer!